# Git gist - Markdown does not work

Tags: git, markdown, gist

I am not able to get Markdown work in a gist. My post is available [here](https://gist.github.com/1556448#comments).

Notice that the same Markdown works when I add a comment.

What did I miss?

Comment: For reference [GitHub Flavored Markdown](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown).

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Github uses file extension to recognize file type. In order to use Markdown in your gist it should have appropriate `.markdown` (or `.md`) extension. See [this](https://gist.github.com/1556552).

Comment: Don't happen to know how they got tables working here: https://gist.github.com/1207002 do you?

Comment: I see now that particular gist's 'type' is set to 'textile', not 'markdown'

Comment: @DeanRather You can do tables with Markdown. See [GitHub Flavored Markdown - Tables](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown#tables).

Comment: When I create Gists, I also notice markdown never works, so typically put the bulk of the content as markdown in the comments, which does work.  It took me some time to figure out you have to edit the "title" of the gist to make it a file name ending with .md.